# Pause signal on Python script does not stop Telnet streamer

Tags: python, stream, telnet, pause, telnetlib

I have the following Python script that works perfectly for my purposes.

I run it like this: `python smoothie-stream.py /path/to/file.gcode 192.168.3.222`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""\
Stream g-code to Smoothie telnet connection

Based on GRBL stream.py
"""

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import telnetlib
import argparse

def write_raw_sequence(tn, seq):
    sock = tn.get_socket()
    if sock is not None:
        sock.send(seq)

# Define command line argument interface
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Stream g-code file to Smoothie over telnet.')
parser.add_argument('gcode_file', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
        help='g-code filename to be streamed')
parser.add_argument('ipaddr',
        help='Smoothie IP address')
parser.add_argument('-q','--quiet',action='store_true', default=False,
        help='suppress output text')
args = parser.parse_args()

f = args.gcode_file
verbose = not args.quiet

# Stream g-code to Smoothie
print("Streaming " + args.gcode_file.name + " to " + args.ipaddr)

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(args.ipaddr)
# turn on prompt
#write_raw_sequence(tn, telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.DO + "\x55")

# read startup prompt
tn.read_until("Smoothie command shell")

okcnt= 0
linecnt= 0
for line in f:
    tn.write(line)
    linecnt+=1
    rep= tn.read_eager()
    okcnt += rep.count("ok")
    if verbose:
        #print("linecnt:" + str(linecnt))
        print("linecnt:" + str(okcnt))

#print("Waiting for complete...")

while okcnt < linecnt:
    rep= tn.read_some()
    okcnt += rep.count("ok")
    if verbose:
        #print("linecnt:" + str(linecnt))
        print("linecnt:" + str(okcnt))

tn.write("exit\n")
tn.read_all()

print("Done")
```

From time to time I need to pause its execution, so I send it the signal `kill -TSTP` (basically hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the console). I can then resume the streaming with `fg` or `bg` successfully. My problem is that the script's execution does NOT pause immediately. With either tcpdump or ngrep I can assure you that it takes anywhere from 30 seconds to a minute to stop streaming (with SEVERAL lines being sent over telnet, at least 50!). I have checked out Python's telnetlib (on [Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/telnetlib.py)) but I am clueless on why the script does not pause immediately.

Comment: You probably cannot pause during a call to write() because you are in kernel-land. It is probably pausing as soon as that syscall finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Does that mean I am screwed? To me it seems that the script gets paused not 1 or 2 write()s late, but about 50!! Which is really weird because there's one write in every loop iteration. I can stand pausing one write() late but not 50. I really need to pause the streaming asynchronically, i.e. I need the signal to not allow any extra "while" loop iterations. Maybe I can use a signal to edit the value of a variable, and check that variable in every iteration? I am pretty sure that a pausing mechanism can be implemented somehow...

Comment: buf = self.sock.recv(25) (instead of 50?)

    def fill_rawq(self):
        """Fill raw queue from exactly one recv() system call.
        Block if no data is immediately available.  Set self.eof when
        connection is closed.
        """
        if self.irawq >= len(self.rawq):
            self.rawq = ''
            self.irawq = 0
        # The buffer size should be fairly small so as to avoid quadratic
        # behavior in process_rawq() above
        buf = self.sock.recv(50)
        self.msg("recv %r", buf)
        self.eof = (not buf)
        self.rawq = self.rawq + buf

Comment: Maybe if I make that 50 smaller I can make some sort of buffer smaller? Cause the lines deffinitely get buffered outside of Python's reach.